# Why isn't my for loop that assigns values to arrays working?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm expecting the program to output all the digits entered, but it is only outputting the last digit in the number over and over again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Example9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //asks user to input the first 9 digits of an ISBN
        System.out.println("Enter first nine digits: ");
        int firstNine = input.nextInt();
        int[] digits = new int[9];
        int digitsLeft = firstNine;
        for(int i = digits.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int digit = firstNine % 10;
            digitsLeft = (int) Math.floor(digitsLeft / 10);
            digits[i] = digit;
            System.out.println(digits[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int digit = firstNine % 10;
```

must be

```
int digit = digitsLeft % 10;
```

Also, with `i > 0` you will not add the first digit. It must be `i >= 0`.